# trying to create a 'macro'/extract to a new data.frame

Tags: r

My problem is that I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
no lines available in input
```

From:

```
setwd("C:/")

lf = list.files(pattern=".csv") 

treat_file = function(f){
  ff = sub("\\.[[:alnum:]]*$", "", f)
  d = read.csv(f, skip=2, sep=",")
  Var2 = sum(d[,3]*d[,5])
  Var3 = 10000*(1/(sum((d[,1]*d[,2])^2)))
  c(as.numeric(ff), Var2, Var3)
} 

newdata = sapply(lf, treat_file)
```

The .csv files look like this:

```
Final Score: 570

Final X, Starting X, Score, Velocity, Success
-6,-210,100,3,1
-19,-279,70,4,0
2,-229,90,3,1
0,-210,100,3,1
19,-329,50,4,0
17,-279,70,4,0
etc,
etc,
etc,
```

**Final Code**

It turns out there was a single file that was empty, which was messing up the sapply. Including message into the function and using lapply showed me where things were going afoul and now it all works.

```
setwd("C:/")

# find all the text files
lf = list.files(pattern=".csv") 
#Make sure they're there
View(lf)

# this function works on a single file
treat_file = function(f){
#this will record where r is processing in case there is an error (blank .csv file)
message("currently reading:", f)
#create column with .csv scrubbed
ff = sub("\\.[[:alnum:]]*$", "", f)
#read in .csv files
d = read.csv(f, skip=2, sep=",")
#create a score variable
Var2 = sum(d[,3]*d[,5])
#create a continuous score variable
Var3 = 10000000*(1/(sum(sqrt((d[,1]*d[,3])^2))))
#combine the three variables
c(as.numeric(ff), Var2, Var3)
} 
#This is a second way of checking how importing the .csv files is going
#shows number of rows and how many columns are in that row
lapply(lf, count.fields, sep=",")

#creates data.frame in which the function is applied to all csv files
#transposes data.frame
newdata = t(sapply(lf, treat_file))
#change column names
colnames(newdata)= c("PIN", "score", "continuous")
#Make sure everything looks good
View(newdata)
```

*Original Post*

Grad student here trying to make my life a little easier, but programming in R is not my specialty. Would really appreciate some help.
So I run an experiment where I get a .csv output for each subject with a title like 1254.csv where the four digit number is unique to each person. My goal is to end up with a data.frame where the first variable is the unique subject number for each person, and the second and third variables are numbers calculated from each .csv file. I'm thinking I should be able to do something similar to:

```
object (or environment) = all .csv files #need help figuring out exactly how I get it into a workable object or what-have-you
for(i in 1:ncol (csvfileobject)) { 
Var1$newdata.frame = nameof i 
Var2$newdata.frame = (sum up the numbers in column2 for each csvfile) 
Var3$newdata.frame = (multiply columns 2 and 5 and sum that up for each csvfile) }
```

Obviously, I'm not looking for someone to do all of the "work" for me, but I'm pretty lost on the programming,aspect of R and could use maybe some direction.
Thanks!

Comment: you could add `message("currently reading:", f)` at the beginning of your `treat_file` function, to see which file(s) is causing trouble. Also, have you checked that the list of files `lf` contains only those files you want to import?

Comment: this doesn't seem to make sense to me: skip=2 works fine for me with or without the comma on the second line. Do you have the problem with every file, or just a few specific ones? Try read.csv on its own without the treat_file function, there is no reason it couldn't cope with these data.

Comment: what do you get when you do `lapply(lf, count.fields, sep=",")`?

Comment: You're a beautiful human being. Yep, my fix wasn't a fix, it just got rid of the problemsome file. lapply and message showed me where it was messing up. I fixed that file and it works perfectly.

Thank you!

Comment: glad it worked out in the end, and pleased to see you seem to be progressing rapidly in R.

Answer (score 2):

I almost stopped reading after `My goal is to end up with an excel sheet`, but anyway, here's a sketch:

```
# find all the text files
lf = list.files(pattern=".txt") 


# this function works on a single file
treat_file = function(f, ...){

  # magic to strip the filename extension
  ff = sub("\\.[[:alnum:]]*$", "", f)
  # read the data into a data.frame
  d = read.table(f, ...)
  # calculate some stuff with the data
  Var2 = sum(d[ ,2]) # summing all the second column
  Var3 = sum(d[ ,2]*d[ ,5]) # etc.

  # results to be returned
  c(as.numeric(ff), Var2, Var3)

} 

# now we apply the function to all files
sapply(lf, treat_file)
```

Comment: you may need to break down the problem into smaller intermediate steps. i) Read one data file into R, figure out what arguments to `?read.table` you need. 2) Make sure `?list.files` returns a sensible list of filenames. 3) test your calculations on one single data.frame.

Comment: Thank you! I've filled the rest of it out and tested the read.csv (they were csv files, not txt files) on a single file and it correctly imported it.

The problem is that when I run this code with read.csv(f, skip=2, sep=",") I get an error: Error in read.table(file=file, header=header, sep=sep, quote=quote, : no lines available in input

Comment: well, since I can't see what you're doing because of various laws of optics, it would probably be best if you could describe in much more details every step you're taking, the result you get, what the files contain, etc. Please edit your question to make it easier for us to know what you're doing.

Comment: I apologize. I have edited the original post with (hopefully) the relevant information.

Comment: I don't mean to be harsh, but there are a few tips that prove useful when asking questions around here. Your question is now better, but we've lost the original context! Ideally when you edited, you would have appended the new info to the original question (otherwise a lot of the replies and comments lose any meaning for future visitors).

Comment: Sorry! I'm new to this site and seem to be messing it all up. On the plus side, I now understand how it works. On the negative, I've been a horses ass. 

I've figured out all of my problems (as the newest, very new edit shows) but I just need to find a way to either delete the second row from every text file or add a comma to every second row, since 'skip' didn't do exactly what I thought it would.

Thank you for the helpful code though, and for anybody who happens to have a similar problem http://thr3ads.net/r-help/2012/11/2117473-error-message-no-lines-available-in-input proved helpful too